# REGEXP_SUBSTR, Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function in oracle to read a field value that varies slightly in character length to extract the first date in the string.

Here are the examples of the values I need to pull the date from:

> 1) Seasonal Begin Date changed from  to 01/02/18.
>
> 2) Seasonal Begin Date changed from 01/05/17 to 01/15/18.
>
> 3) Seasonal Begin Date changed to 01/03/2018.

From these examples I would need the following values extracted:

> 1) 01/02/18
>
> 2) 01/05/18
>
> 3) 01/03/2018

I've done a bit of research regarding REGEXP_SUBSTR but I'm stumped on how to address these three different values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The main problem is that computers (other than AI) don't know what a "date" is supposed to look like in the middle of a string. You need to break it down into concepts the computer understands. So, for example - from the strings you show - you may say *a date is a substring surrounded by spaces, or the beginning or the end of the string. This substring contains exactly two slashes and everything else is digits. The first and second "numbers" within the "date" are one or two digits; and the last "number" is either two or four digits.* Of course, this will not see `03-15-2016` as a date.

Comment: Nor will it VALIDATE the date; you may very well have `99/99/9999` in your input string, and the regexp solution will not "see" that it is not a date. (You can write further validation but that is an entirely different issue.)

Comment: This is good feedback - thank you for the your input. I'm looking to explore other options via SUBSTR for this particular issue.

Are you saying that there's a way to query this string to search for numbers before and before the ' / / '?

Seasonal Begin Date changed from to 01/02/18.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` to match a number of days between 1 and 31,
- `(0?[1-9]|1[012])` to match a number of months between 1 and 12 and
- `\d{2}\d{2}?` to match a 2-digit or 4-digit year.

Which you can use like this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(
           your_input,
           '(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/\d{2}\d{2}?'
         ),
         'DD/MM/YY'
       ) As first_date
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Not sure about the partial validation. Since the solution will not "object" to 31/04/2013 (even though April has only 30 days), why even bother to check that the "day" portion is <= 31?

Comment: Also, the search pattern should probably be delimited somehow; in general, this solution will match `11/11/5555` in the input `'part AB835211/11/5555244X-32 was purchased on 03/31/2015'` - the so-called "mother is in che**mother**apy" problem.